# Blurred text appears clean on mouse highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am blurring my container text using text-shadow with below code:

```css
.blur-style{
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(128,128,128);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-style">This is blurred text.</div>
```

It works fine. However, the text is clearly visible when I highlight it!
Desired behavior: Text should remain in its blurred state upon highlighting.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're best bet is to just PREVENT selecting that particular text. Neither really prevents a motivated user from getting the text directly from the DOM.

```css
.blur-style{
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(128,128,128);
user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-style">This is blurred text.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase. I have a button on my page that toggles the blur state. So when the blur state is OFF, the user is allowed to copy the text.

Comment: That makes sense, this style would only apply while the blur was also applied.

Comment: Oh! My bad. You are correct.
But I just added property and it doesn't seem to work! That's strange.

Comment: Stange fix: Since the container has contenteditable=true, switching it to false on blur disables the selection provided the user-select property is set.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property ::selection selector to your css. The ::selection selector matches the portion of an element that is selected by a user.

Only a few CSS properties can be applied to the ::selection selector: color, background, cursor, and outline.

```css
.blur-style{
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(128,128,128);
}

.blur-style::selection {
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(128,128,128);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-style">This is blurred text.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your code and add the ::selection pseudostyle.

Add **this**:

```
.blur-style::selection {
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(128,128,128);
}
```